# How to modify chrome://settings via Puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, puppeteer, browser-automation

I'm using Puppeteer to drive my chrome but I can't find any function to deal with chrome://settings.
I was going to manually browse to chrome://settings and then change the settings, but unfortunately page.goto needs a protocol and chrome://settings doesn't have one.
How can I modify my chrome://settings with Puppeteer?

Comment: You won't be able to automate that, you can try to see if there's any command argument flag that enables/disables the feature you want to change

Comment: I want to enable protected content playback chrome://settings/content/protectedContent and it looks like there's no command line argument for that

Comment: Did you try `--unsafely-allow-protected-media-identifier-for-domain`?

Comment: Tried it now and it doesn't work, unfortunately.There must be a way to change these settings via chrome://settings/content/protectedContent..                  page.goto doesn't work because it needs a protocol, but there must be a workaround

Comment: Did you manage to edit those settings? I'm currently trying to enable those exact same settings